# Django annotate returns result in memory

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, orm

I've the following call in Django:

```
Activity.objects.values('user_field__username').annotate(Sum('reward'))
```

Given below is the schema of my "Activity" table:

- User (foreign key to user model)
- Reward

Each user can have around dozen entries in this table. There can be 10 million users.

I want to get the total reward of each user and send notification to all such users at one time. The above query satisfied my requirement but i was told that its suboptimal and would have huge space complexity. What's the right thing to do in principle.

My Activity model :

```
class Activity(models.Model):
    user_field = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), default=0)
    reward = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: You better query in the opposite way, like `User.objects.annotate(Sum('activity__reward'))`. You will fetch the users into memory as well. But ten million will likely fail anway, since Python is not good with processing 100k+ elements. If you thus can filter the total reward further at the database level, that can improve the efficiencly significantly.

Comment: Can you explain what's happening in the background there @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: Would be great if you can point me to the documentation to the reverse call you've mentioned. I couldn't find it.

Comment: It would by default be `User.activity_set` unless you code `related_name` on the ForeignKey in Activity. It's in the Django documentation, under model fields type ForeignKey I think.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem , the query mentioned by you returns <QuerySet [<User: jaisharma>, <User: test1>]> while the one i mentioned returns <QuerySet [{u'user_field__username': u'jaisharma', 'user_reward': 1000}, {u'user_field__username': u'test1', 'user_reward': 400}]>

Comment: @JaiSharma annotations add an attribute to each object in the queryset so you could access the reward by `User.objects.annotate(reward=Sum('activity__reward'))[0].reward`

Comment: @JaiSharma: an annotation will add an extra attribute for the model objects that arise from the queryset.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work for me. AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'reward'. As i mentioned, it returns User model object.